# Save player data in Java Script

Tags: javascript, github, save

I currently and making a RPG game in java script for a github.io website. Its going well, but I want players to be able to save data. I am unsure how I could do this. For an example lets say I want to save that they are a Mage. This is what I thought of:

1: save "Mage" in the browsers cookies (I don't know how, and I would prefer to not do it this way if I did)

2: encrypt "Mage" into a text file that they would load into the game. (This would be annoying to do as a user)

3: save "Mage" in a file on the site then they could choose a username/password and log-in to get data. (This would be preferable, but I have no idea how to do it on a github.io site.

"Mage" is just an example and I would be saving more detailed things.

I am kinda new to Java Script, however I do know java, so if there is a way to do it with java.

number 3 would be preferred, but I could go with any. I have no idea how to do any of them, and help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered to use [HTML5 local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Comment: If I am right that would not let users access from multiple computers, I am mostly doing this for school, and school computers will clear all data after the window is closed, even if saved like this.

Comment: certainly in that case local storage is not an option. Maybe you can use a database but the options are limited. You can google that until a better answer show up.